# How send with post method in code behind?

Tags: php

I have a param A and its  25000 characters long.
How to send param A with `GET` method in php?

```
 $kq=0;
 $msg1= strtr(base64_encode($msg), '+/=', '-_,');              
 $Title1=strtr(base64_encode($Title), '+/=', '-_,'); 
header("Location:".JRoute::_('./index.php/i0702?'.'kq='.$kq."&Title=".$Title1."&Msg=".$msg1));
```

Note: strlen($msg1)> 25000 characters. Now, How send with post method?

Comment: You should avoid doing such a long HTTP `GET` request. Make it a `POST` request; some HTTP clients and servers may accept a long `GET` request, others don't.

Comment: Simple: you don't. Why does it have to be in the URL?

Comment: Why do you GET method for this. You can use POST as suggested by GBD.

Comment: How open 1 url with method POST?

Comment: What is the use case? Provide more context so we can properly answer the question.

Comment: @deceze. i send with get as my edit.

Comment: You can to use $_SESSION

Answer (score 1):

The maximum characters you can send from `GET` method is 3000. Use POST method.

```
<form method="POST" action="your/url/to/open.php">

    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: How open 1 url with method POST? IN CODE BEHIND

Comment: @mum, On my example put the URL as `action="...."` in the form.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of an http request relies both on client and server to handle it... and it changes depending on what combination of client/server you are using.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) is an explanation of why a 25K HTTP GET request is not feasible in the real world unless you can choose both the client and the server you are operating on (definitely not an internet site, maybe for an intranet application).

Switching to an HTTP POST request is recommended (an HTML form can handle this). If this is not possible for you, you should consider refactoring your application data flow.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're redirecting within the same page, save the large data server-side in a session or database and only put a small id which allows you to retrieve this data again into the URL.